# Why is my wooden fence leaning/bulging inwards and how do I fix it?

Tags: wood, fence

I have a wooden fence in the backyard that came with the house when I bought it five years ago. One small section has started leaning inwards, to the point where I'm now concerned in a big storm it might fall over entirely, and I need it to contain my dog in our own yard. What can I do to fix this up without spending too much money?

[image]

Comment: We really need to see pictures of the posts holding the fence in the ground.  They could be rotten, in which case replacement is the only option.  Also, check your property lines to make sure the fence is on your property and not your neighbors'.  It's often a requirement to put the "nice" side of the fence on the outside of the property, so since your view seems to be the "nice" side, then it's possible the fence is actually your neighbors' responsibility to maintain/repair.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I repair a fence that's leaning due to soft soil?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/122743/how-should-i-repair-a-fence-thats-leaning-due-to-soft-soil)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I repair a fence that's leaning due to soft soil?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/122743/how-should-i-repair-a-fence-thats-leaning-due-to-soft-soil)

Comment: Not sure how to fix up this question -- I got a pro to come over and look and he says there's four fence posts that need to be replaced.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like the post failed and the only thing holding that section of fence up is the rest of the fence.

The absolute cheapest way of "fixing" that is by adding a bit of lumber diagonally from the ground to the top of the fence as a support (after pushing it back up to plumb):

[image]

This has fairly obvious downsides. Especially if your dog is a capable climber.

More involved fixes will require fixing the post itself by replacing it.